# How to remove items from smaller lists that are in a larger list?

Tags: python, list

Hi I have one big list which consist of 10 smaller list. In each smaller list are 10 random numbers.
Depending on the variable, either even or not even variables must be visible.The example below I made only for 2 smaller lists to make it easier to see the output.

This is my code.

```
def generate_random_number_list_10(len_of_elements):

    my_list=[random.randint(1,100) for x in range (len_of_elements)]
    return my_list

def generate_list_consist_of_10_smaller_list(amount_of_list,len_of_elements,variable):

    big_list=[generate_random_number_list_10(len_of_elements) for x in range (amount_of_list)]
    print (big_list)
    if variable%2 == 0:
        for num in big_list :
            for x in num:
                filtered_list = list(filter(lambda x: x%2==0, num)) 

    print (filtered_list)


generate_list_consist_of_10_smaller_list(2,8,8)
```

This is my output:

```
[[1, 47, 25, 84, 48, 8, 91, 89], [99, 40, 54, 50, 52, 83, 86, 61]] - for example big list cosist of 2 smaller list
[40, 54, 50, 52, 86] - my solution is correct only for last smaller list
```

```
[[ 84, 48, 8], [ 40, 54, 50, 52, 86]] -this is correct solution
```

For a larger number of smaller lists, my solution filters even numbers only for the last smaller list.
How to apply filtering to all smaller lists, regardless of how many there are?

Comment: You're not creating a list of all the filtered lists, you're just overwriting the variable each time.

Answer (score 1):

`filtered_list` needs to be a list of lists.

Also, you don't need the `for x` loop, since `filter()` does that looping automatically.

```
def generate_list_consist_of_10_smaller_list(amount_of_list,len_of_elements,variable):
    big_list=[generate_random_number_list_10(len_of_elements) for x in range (amount_of_list)]
    print (big_list)
    if variable%2 == 0:
        filtered_list = [list(filter(lambda x: x%2==0, num)) for num in big_list]
        print (filtered_list)
```

Comment: OK thanks, but know I need a save output in .txt file. I wanted such a file to be generated both when we enter an even and odd variable. Can you do it using Context Manager, because my friend told me something about this solution

Comment: The function should return the list instead of printing it. Then the caller can do whatever they want with the result: print it, write it to a file, etc. That's unrelated to how you create the list.